# Access violation writing location, in my loop

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

The exact error I am getting is

```
First-chance exception at 0x0096234a in chp2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x002b0000.
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in chp2.exe.
```

And the breakpoint stops here

```
for(DWORD i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    //we are start at the top of z
    float z = halfDepth - i*dx;
    for(DWORD j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        //to the left of us
        float x = -halfWidth + j*dx;
        float y = 0.0f;
        vertices[i*n+j].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, z); //<----- Right here
        vertices[i*n+j].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. below is the code in its entirety

```
#include "MyGame.h"
//#include "CubeVector.h"
/* This code sets a projection and shows a turning cube. What has been added is the project, rotation and
a rasterizer to change the rasterization of the cube. The issue that was going on was something with the effect file
which was causing the vertices not to be rendered correctly.*/
typedef struct 
{
    ID3D10Effect* pEffect;
    ID3D10EffectTechnique* pTechnique;

    //vertex information
    ID3D10Buffer* pVertexBuffer;
    ID3D10Buffer* pIndicesBuffer;
    ID3D10InputLayout* pVertexLayout;

    UINT numVertices;
    UINT numIndices;
}ModelObject;

ModelObject modelObject;
// World Matrix
D3DXMATRIX                  WorldMatrix;
// View Matrix
D3DXMATRIX                  ViewMatrix;
// Projection Matrix
D3DXMATRIX                  ProjectionMatrix;
ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* pProjectionMatrixVariable = NULL;

//grid information
#define NUM_COLS 16
#define NUM_ROWS 16

#define CELL_WIDTH 32
#define CELL_HEIGHT 32

#define NUM_VERTSX (NUM_COLS + 1)
#define NUM_VERTSY (NUM_ROWS + 1)




bool MyGame::InitDirect3D()
{
    if(!DX3dApp::InitDirect3D())
    {
        return false;
    }

    D3D10_RASTERIZER_DESC rastDesc;
    rastDesc.FillMode = D3D10_FILL_WIREFRAME;
    rastDesc.CullMode = D3D10_CULL_FRONT;
    rastDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
    rastDesc.DepthBias = false;
    rastDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0;
    rastDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0;
    rastDesc.DepthClipEnable = false;
    rastDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rastDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rastDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;

    ID3D10RasterizerState *g_pRasterizerState;
    mpD3DDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&rastDesc, &g_pRasterizerState);
    mpD3DDevice->RSSetState(g_pRasterizerState);

    // Set up the World Matrix
    //The first line of code creates your identity matrix. Second line of code
    //second combines your camera position, target location, and which way is up respectively
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&WorldMatrix);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&ViewMatrix, new D3DXVECTOR3(200.0f, 60.0f, -20.0f), new D3DXVECTOR3(200.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f), new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    // Set up the projection matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&ProjectionMatrix, (float)D3DX_PI * 0.5f, (float)mWidth/(float)mHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    if(!CreateObject())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

//These are actions that take place after the clearing of the buffer and before the present
void MyGame::GameDraw()
{

    static float rotationAngle = 0.0f;

    // create the rotation matrix using the rotation angle
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&WorldMatrix, rotationAngle);
    rotationAngle += (float)D3DX_PI * 0.0f;

    // Set the input layout
    mpD3DDevice->IASetInputLayout(modelObject.pVertexLayout);

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(VertexPos);
    UINT offset = 0;
    mpD3DDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &modelObject.pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    mpD3DDevice->IASetIndexBuffer(modelObject.pIndicesBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // Set primitive topology
    mpD3DDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // Combine and send the final matrix to the shader
    D3DXMATRIX finalMatrix = (WorldMatrix * ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix);
    pProjectionMatrixVariable->SetMatrix((float*)&finalMatrix);


    // make sure modelObject is valid


    // Render a model object
    D3D10_TECHNIQUE_DESC techniqueDescription;
    modelObject.pTechnique->GetDesc(&techniqueDescription);

    // Loop through the technique passes
    for(UINT p=0; p < techniqueDescription.Passes; ++p)
    {
        modelObject.pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);
        // draw the cube using all 36 vertices and 12 triangles
        mpD3DDevice->DrawIndexed(modelObject.numIndices,0,0);
    }
}

//Render actually incapsulates Gamedraw, so you can call data before you actually clear the buffer or after you 
//present data
void MyGame::Render()
{
    DX3dApp::Render();
}

bool MyGame::CreateObject()
{
    //dx will represent the width and the height of the spacing of each vector
    float dx = 1;
    //Below are the number of vertices
    //m is the vertices of each row. n is the columns
    DWORD m = 30;
    DWORD n = 30;
    //This get the width of the entire land
    //30 - 1 = 29 rows * 1 = 29 * 0.5 = 14.5
    float halfWidth = (n-1)*dx*0.5f;
    float halfDepth = (m-1)*dx*0.5f;
    float vertexsize = m * n;
    VertexPos vertices[80];

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        //we are start at the top of z
        float z = halfDepth - i*dx;
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            //to the left of us
            float x = -halfWidth + j*dx;
            float y = 0.0f;
            vertices[i*n+j].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, z);
            vertices[i*n+j].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }

    int k = 0;

    DWORD indices[540];
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
        for(DWORD j = 0; j < n-1; ++j)
        {
            indices[k]      = (i * n) + j;
            indices[k + 1]  = (i * n) + j + 1;
            indices[k + 2]  = (i + 1) * n  + j;

            indices[k + 3]  = (i + 1) * n  + j;
            indices[k + 4]  = (i * n) + j + 1;
            indices[k + 5]  = (i + 1) * n  + j+ 1;

            k += 6;
        }
    }




    //Create Layout
    D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = {
        {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0 , 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0 , 12, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    UINT numElements = (sizeof(layout)/sizeof(layout[0]));
    modelObject.numVertices = sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(VertexPos);

    //Create buffer desc
    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexPos) * modelObject.numVertices;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    initData.pSysMem = vertices;
    //Create the buffer

    HRESULT hr = mpD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, &modelObject.pVertexBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    modelObject.numIndices = sizeof(indices)/sizeof(DWORD);

    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * modelObject.numIndices;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;

    initData.pSysMem = indices;

    hr = mpD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, &modelObject.pIndicesBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Set up fx files
    LPCWSTR effectFilename = L"effect.fx";
    modelObject.pEffect = NULL;

     hr = D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile(effectFilename,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        "fx_4_0",
        D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS,
        0,
        mpD3DDevice,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &modelObject.pEffect,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    pProjectionMatrixVariable = modelObject.pEffect->GetVariableByName("Projection")->AsMatrix();
    //Dont sweat the technique. Get it!
    LPCSTR effectTechniqueName = "Render";

    modelObject.pTechnique = modelObject.pEffect->GetTechniqueByName(effectTechniqueName);
    if(modelObject.pTechnique == NULL)
        return false;


    //Create Vertex layout
    D3D10_PASS_DESC passDesc;
    modelObject.pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);

    hr = mpD3DDevice->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements,
        passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize,
        &modelObject.pVertexLayout);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 30 vertices in each row and 30 in each column how come vertices is defined as

```
VertexPos vertices[80];
```

This line:

```
vertices[i*n+j].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, z);
```

writes past the end of the vertices array whenever i * n + j > 79 (e.g, if i = 10 then i * n + j >= 300)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I figure if I got a vertices is corrupted error message then that would be the case. But I guess an array that goes past its bounds can have multiple error messages

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you're writing past the end of the vertices array or trying to read from invalid variables (empty). Make sure your array is of the proper size.

Answer (score 2):

Your vertices array has size of 80. In worst case, You are trying to write in vertices[i*n+j], where i=30, n=30, j=30, so You are trying to address vertices[930].

Not intended, is it ?

Comment: Isn't the worst case i=29, n=30, j=29? Leading to an access to vertices[899]?